# Video, Audio, and Microphone Recording - Windows

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I'm looking for a program that records my screen, audio output to my speakers, and audio input (microphone). Does there exist a software capable of doing this? I'm primarily interested in Windows, but willing to try Linux ones too.

Price: less than $150 USD, but of course, cheaper is always better
Format: Any popular format should be okay

Comment: Records to what format? Price? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Tosh, it doesn't help to [delete your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28197/185) and ask it again, ignoring all requests for more details (and even make it broader). Again, fill the gaps please: a) limits in recording lenght vs. auto-split into multiple files, b) recording quality and formats / compression vs quality vs resolution, c) easy-to-use GUI with xyz (buttons/controls/…), d) load it puts on the computer while running, e) dependencies/size of the application, f) price. **[edit]** your post to include those – don't delete/repost a 4th time.

Comment: Izzy, there were no comments on the original question when I deleted it - I saw your comment on that question just now. I deleted that question since I realized my original question has already been asked and answered, in many questions in fact, under the tag "screen-recording".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TechSmith Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html):

- non-free
- can record thescreen, audio output to the speakers, and audio input (e.g., microphone)
- easy-to-use GUI
- many choices of recording quality and formats / compression vs quality vs resolution

[image]